# Merge with replacement of smaller dataframe to larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames that look like this:

DF1:

```
index  colA colB
 id1    0     0
 id2    0     0
 id3    0     0
 id4    0     0
 id5    0     0
```

DF2:

```
index  colA   colB
  id3    A3     B3
  id4    A4     B4
  id6    A6     B6
```

I want to infuse values from `DF2` to `DF1`. I was trying to merge but it does not replace the values and creates newer columns. The resulting DataFrame I want should look like this:

DF1:

```
index  colA  colB
  id1     0     0
  id2     0     0
  id3    A3    B3
  id4    A4    B4
  id5     0     0
  id6    A6    B6
```

Note: it should create a new index in `DF1` if `DF2` has some index not present in `DF1`. Also columns `index` are the index of DataFrames and not column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `concat` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
out = pd.concat((df1, df2)).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['index'], keep='last').set_index('index').sort_index()
```

or use `reindex` + `update`:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index))
df1.update(df2)
```

Output:

```
  index colA colB
0   id1    0    0
1   id2    0    0
0   id3   A3   B3
1   id4   A4   B4
4   id5    0    0
2   id6   A6   B6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `combine_first`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('index')
df2 = df2.set_index('index')
out = df2.combine_first(df1)
Out[217]: 
      colA colB
index          
id1    0.0  0.0
id2    0.0  0.0
id3     A3   B3
id4     A4   B4
id5    0.0  0.0
id6     A6   B6
```